# Google treats vbscript as exact match of cscript, how do I deal with that?

Tags: google-search

When I google for CSCript refference, google returns VBScript results. Even when I put CScript in quotes.

[Have a look](https://www.google.cz/search?q=get%20text%20from%20user%20%2B%22cscript%22):

[image: image description]

I don't want to match `vbscript` but also I don't want to exclude vbcript results since vbscript and cscript documentation is often merged. How do I stop google from treating cscript and vbscript as synonyms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the `+` eg [get text from user "cscript"](http://google.com/search?q=get+text+from+user+%22cscript%22) although that doesn't differ much from your [get text from user +"cscript"](https://www.google.cz/search?q=get%20text%20from%20user%20%2B%22cscript%22) *See images below*

**Mine:**
[image: mine]

**Yours:**
[image: Yours]

---

<del>Try using the `minus search operator` <sup>1</sup>

eg [get text from user +"cscript" -VBscript](http://google.com/search?q=get+text+from+user+%2B%22cscript%22+-VBscript)



<sup>1</sup> My term for it - more details can be found on Google's [advance search page](https://www.google.com/advanced_search)</del>

Comment: From the question: "**but also I don't exclude vbcript results since vbscript and cscript documentation is often merged**"

Comment: I wanted to write "don't want to" though.

Comment: @TomášZato see update  - sorry I was ignorant and didn't read your question properly

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't solve the problem. How does exactly use of lmgtfy.com work different than google? I wonder whether whoever upvoted this answer tried to click on the link... It gives exactly the same results as my original search.

Comment: Interesting, for me they are slightly different http://imgur.com/a/thIpG see last result of images. Also note that VBScript in the descriptions isn't **highlighted**

Comment: Sorry, I see that now. Apparently, the `+` is then making it worse, rather than better.

Comment: I think the more interesting difference between them is if you look at the links at the top on [google.com.au](http://google.com.au) vs [google.cz](http://google.cz) `shopping` `images` and `news` are in different spots.
Sorry for adding the lmgtfu.com links I couldn't resist

Comment: LMGTFY links should not be used as they are found for many people as disrespectful.

Comment: fair point, have removed

Answer (score 0):

It's incorrect to say that Google takes **vscript** as an exact math of **cscript** based on the first results that it returns.

Google results are based on their relevance related to the search keywords used and considering that CScript supports VBScripts the displayed results are relevant.

## References

- [Filter your search results - Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/142143?hl=en)
- [Search operators - Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en)
- [Using the command-based script host (CScript.exe) - Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490887.aspx)